# System hangs after running master cluster kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Whenever I try to run the Kubernetes cluster from the master’s machine using the below command, my system hangs and gets very slow and I even cant open explorer, or firefox. I have two VM with network configuration NAT and Host-only adapter.

```
 kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=<ip-address-of-kmaster-vm> --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Which VM are you using (VirtualBox, VMVare)? Could you elaborate your scenario? You are on the VM machine (its linux, debian, centos?) and installe docker, kubeadm, etc and now you want to initialize kubeadm on master (which is VM). How much CPU and RAM have this VM? Please provide more information.

Comment: Hi @PjoterS, Thank you very much I sorted out the problem based on your question you asked about CPU and RAM on the VM. It gave a hint and direction, my RAM was 2GB which was causing the issue to hang. I set to 4GB now it's working perfectly fine

Comment: Ive posted answer for better visibility for community. @abaair davis Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was discussed in comments, the root cause of the issue was not enough resources available in this VirtualMachine.

In [Kubeadm documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#before-you-begin), minimal requirements are:

> To follow this guide, you need:
>
> - One or more machines running a deb/rpm-compatible Linux OS; for example: Ubuntu or CentOS.
> - **2 GiB or more of RAM per machine--any less leaves little room for your apps.**
> - **At least 2 CPUs on the machine that you use as a control-plane node.**
> - Full network connectivity among all machines in the cluster. You can use either a public or a private network.

OP's VM had set RAM to `2GB` which casued performance issue using different applications.

When RAM on the VM was set to `4GB`, Virtual Machine is working perfectly fine.